# Wordpress query 'post_name__in' => array( $exploded array ) not working

Tags: arrays, wordpress

I have an array that I exploded and sucessfully echo'd but if I try using it in my query it want work.

```
$result_string = "'" . str_replace(",", "', '", $hexcode) . "'";
echo $result_string;
```

this echo's 'DimGray', 'DarkGray', 'Black', 'Sienna' 
My args array looks like that:

```
$args = array (
                    'post_type'              => array( 'farben' ),
                    'post_status'            => array( 'publish' ),
                    'order'                  => 'ASC',
                    'orderby'                => 'menu_order',
                    'post_name__in' => array( 'DimGray', 'DarkGray', 'Black', 'Sienna' )

                );
```

this also works. But what do I need to do to echo my string in the post_name__in array? I tryed this:

```
'post_name__in' => array( $result_string )
```

But it want work. Any Ideas? Thank you for any tips.

Comment: Make `result_string` an array. then use => $result_string https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#post-page-parameters

Comment: can you post a sample string that you want to use in the query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to replace all with below:

```html
$result_string = explode(',',$hexcode);
$args = array (
    'post_type'              => array( 'farben' ),
    'post_status'            => array( 'publish' ),
    'order'                  => 'ASC',
    'orderby'                => 'menu_order',
    'post_name__in' => $result_string
);
```

Let me know it's work for you or not.

Comment: Oh my gush you are my hero!!! Thank you so much! Why does it seem so easy now! :-)